# How Do I Make A Graphical User Interface Or Any Thing Else In Lua

Tags: lua

I Am New To Lua And Cant Understand Where To Start. I Have Watched A Lot Of Videos But They Don't Quite Solve My Problem. All I Want Is A Graphical User Interface In Lua In Zero Brane Studios

Help Would Be Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd start from [sample applications that come bundled with wxlua project](https://github.com/pkulchenko/wxlua/tree/master/wxLua/samples) (which is a wrapper around wxwidgets that ZeroBrane Studio is using as its GUI library). The samples range from a [very simple](https://github.com/pkulchenko/wxlua/blob/master/wxLua/samples/minimal.wx.lua) to something that resembles a [fully-functional editor](https://github.com/pkulchenko/wxlua/blob/master/wxLua/samples/editor.wx.lua) and you can run all of them directly from ZeroBrane Studio (just set the project to the samples/ folder, open any of the files and run them).

You can then look at how the things that you're interested in are done in other projects. ZeroBrane Studio itself is written in Lua, so you can see all its code and explore how all its components interact and how specific parts are implemented.

Keep in mind that there are other GUI toolkits that may be available from Lua. For example, [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) and [Lua bindings for Dear IMGUI](https://github.com/patrickriordan/imgui_lua_bindings).